# Question on divisibility by 3. Prove that a²-36=8 is not true for any natural numbers a and b.

Tags: divisibility

**Prove that there are no natural numbers a and b such that a²-36b=8**.

A hint is given in the solutions that we should check the remainders by mod 3. But do we have to take remainders of whole expression or a and b seperately ?

Comment: What is the `b`? Where is that?

Comment: You mean $a^2 - 36 b = 8$?
If it's so : 1) Prove that $a$ is even and put $a = 2 c$. 2) Prove that $c$ is even. 3) Deduce.

Comment: @Essaidi I think that the OP wanted to write $a^2-3b=8$.

Comment: In both cases , modulo $3$ the equation becomes $a^2=2$ which has no integer solution.

Comment: $a^2\equiv 36+8\equiv 2\pmod{3}$ is unsolvable since $2$ is not a square $\!\bmod 3\,$ - see  the linked dupes.

Comment: The original question is a²-36b=8.